# Google Visualization CategoryFilter - Is it possible to exclude selected value?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have provided a working example `CategoryFilter` in a Google visualization dashboard.
When you make a selection it filters the table and shows only the selected value results.

Is it possible to have a `CategoryFilter` *exclude* the selected value?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls', 'charteditor']
});

renderChart_onPageLoad();

function renderChart_onPageLoad() {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawTable();
  }); //END setOnLoadCallback
} //END function renderChart_onEvent

function drawTable() {
  var jsonArray = jsonDataArray_1to1(json);

  //Modify header row to include id and label
  jsonArray = arrayHeaderRow_id_label_date(jsonArray);
  console.log('jsonArray'); console.log(jsonArray);

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonArray, false); // 'false' means that the first row contains labels, not data.
  //console.log('data');
  //console.log(data);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'div_categoryPicker1',
    'matchType': 'any',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': 0, //Column used in control
      'ui': {
        'label': 'Is exclude selection possible?',
        //'labelSeparator': ':',
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false,
        'allowNone': true
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);

}





//Library

function jsonDataArray_1to1(json) {
  //DYNAMIC JSON ARRAY

  var dataArray_cln = [];

  //A. The desired table requires the fixed columns of ..... to ..... these are directly taken from the JSON.
  var dataArray_keys = Object.keys(json[0]);

  dataArray_cln.push(dataArray_keys);

  //Add rows 1 to json.length with null values
  var dataArray_rows = json.length;
  var dataArray_cols = dataArray_keys.length;

  for (i = 0; i < dataArray_rows; i++) {
    dataArray_cln.push(Array(dataArray_cols).fill(null));
  }

  //Update array from json data
  for (i = 0; i < dataArray_rows; i++) {
    //[i + 1] because row 0 is the header, push begins with row 1
    //dataArray_cln[row][col]

    //Content in row "i" is positioned into dataArray_cln[row][col] incrementing "j" to pull each key name from dataArray_keys
    for (var j = 0; j < dataArray_keys.length; j++) {
      eval('dataArray_cln[i + 1][' + j + '] = json[i].' + dataArray_keys[j]);
    }
  }

  //console.log(dataArray_cln);
  return dataArray_cln;
}

function arrayHeaderRow_id_label_date(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
    var valueOrig = arr[0][i];
    var valueNew;
    switch (true) {
      case valueOrig === 'wd':
        valueNew = JSON.parse('{"id":"' + valueOrig + '", "label":"' + valueOrig + '", "type": "date"}');
        break;
      default:
        valueNew = JSON.parse('{"id":"' + valueOrig + '", "label": "' + valueOrig + '"}');
    }
    arr[0][i] = valueNew;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id='div_dashboard'>
  <div id='div_categoryPicker1'></div>
  <div id='div_table'></div>
</div>

<div id="output1"></div><br/>
<div id="output2"></div><br/>
<div id="output3"></div><br/>

<script>
  var json = [{
      "division": "GS",
      "m1": 100.000000,
      "m2": 100.000000,
      "m3": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "GS",
      "m1": 100.000000,
      "m2": 90.000000,
      "m3": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "PS",
      "m1": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m3": 100.000000,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": 100.000000,
      "m6": 100.000000,
      "m7": 75.000000,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "PS",
      "m1": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m3": 100.000000,
      "m4": 100.000000,
      "m5": 100.000000,
      "m6": 100.000000,
      "m7": 80.000000,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    }
  ];

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can draw the table and category filter independently, without the dashboard,
then use the `'statechange'` event on the category filter to set a filter on the table.

```
var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'div_categoryPicker1',
  dataTable: data,
  'matchType': 'any',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 0, //Column used in control
    'ui': {
      'label': 'Is exclude selection possible?',
      //'labelSeparator': ':',
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false,
      'allowNone': true
    }
  }
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker1, 'statechange', function () {
  var visibleRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
    column: categoryPicker1.getOption('filterColumnIndex'),
    test: function (value) {
      return (categoryPicker1.getState().selectedValues.indexOf(value) === -1);
    }
  }]);

  table.setView({
    rows: visibleRows
  });
  table.draw();
});

var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'Table',
  containerId: 'div_table',
  dataTable: data,
  options: {
    allowHtml: true
  }
});

table.draw();
categoryPicker1.draw();
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls', 'charteditor']
});

renderChart_onPageLoad();

function renderChart_onPageLoad() {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawTable();
  }); //END setOnLoadCallback
} //END function renderChart_onEvent

function drawTable() {
  var jsonArray = jsonDataArray_1to1(json);

  //Modify header row to include id and label
  jsonArray = arrayHeaderRow_id_label_date(jsonArray);
  console.log('jsonArray'); console.log(jsonArray);

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonArray, false); // 'false' means that the first row contains labels, not data.
  //console.log('data');
  //console.log(data);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'div_categoryPicker1',
    dataTable: data,
    'matchType': 'any',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': 0, //Column used in control
      'ui': {
        'label': 'Is exclude selection possible?',
        //'labelSeparator': ':',
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false,
        'allowNone': true
      }
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker1, 'statechange', function () {
    var visibleRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: categoryPicker1.getOption('filterColumnIndex'),
      test: function (value) {
        return (categoryPicker1.getState().selectedValues.indexOf(value) === -1);
      }
    }]);

    table.setView({
      rows: visibleRows
    });
    table.draw();
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  table.draw();
  categoryPicker1.draw();

}





//Library

function jsonDataArray_1to1(json) {
  //DYNAMIC JSON ARRAY

  var dataArray_cln = [];

  //A. The desired table requires the fixed columns of ..... to ..... these are directly taken from the JSON.
  var dataArray_keys = Object.keys(json[0]);

  dataArray_cln.push(dataArray_keys);

  //Add rows 1 to json.length with null values
  var dataArray_rows = json.length;
  var dataArray_cols = dataArray_keys.length;

  for (i = 0; i < dataArray_rows; i++) {
    dataArray_cln.push(Array(dataArray_cols).fill(null));
  }

  //Update array from json data
  for (i = 0; i < dataArray_rows; i++) {
    //[i + 1] because row 0 is the header, push begins with row 1
    //dataArray_cln[row][col]

    //Content in row "i" is positioned into dataArray_cln[row][col] incrementing "j" to pull each key name from dataArray_keys
    for (var j = 0; j < dataArray_keys.length; j++) {
      eval('dataArray_cln[i + 1][' + j + '] = json[i].' + dataArray_keys[j]);
    }
  }

  //console.log(dataArray_cln);
  return dataArray_cln;
}

function arrayHeaderRow_id_label_date(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
    var valueOrig = arr[0][i];
    var valueNew;
    switch (true) {
      case valueOrig === 'wd':
        valueNew = JSON.parse('{"id":"' + valueOrig + '", "label":"' + valueOrig + '", "type": "date"}');
        break;
      default:
        valueNew = JSON.parse('{"id":"' + valueOrig + '", "label": "' + valueOrig + '"}');
    }
    arr[0][i] = valueNew;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id='div_dashboard'>
  <div id='div_categoryPicker1'></div>
  <div id='div_table'></div>
</div>

<div id="output1"></div><br/>
<div id="output2"></div><br/>
<div id="output3"></div><br/>

<script>
  var json = [{
      "division": "GS",
      "m1": 100.000000,
      "m2": 100.000000,
      "m3": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "GS",
      "m1": 100.000000,
      "m2": 90.000000,
      "m3": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "PS",
      "m1": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m3": 100.000000,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": 100.000000,
      "m6": 100.000000,
      "m7": 75.000000,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "PS",
      "m1": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m3": 100.000000,
      "m4": 100.000000,
      "m5": 100.000000,
      "m6": 100.000000,
      "m7": 80.000000,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    }
  ];

</script>
```